# ActiveRecord: Get all keys after group in single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have defined a scope that group a column. For example here is my short code:

```
scope :active, lambda{ some query here }
scope :product_active, lambda{ active.group(:product_id).select(:product_id) }
```

In scope `product_active`, I have grouped by `product_id`. Now, I want to get only "product_ids", how can I do this in single line.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pluck(:product_id)` instead of `select(:product_id)` ?

Comment: @TarynEast thanks. It works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pluck("products.id")` at the end of your scope..if its in the association model to product else `pluck("id")` if its in `product.rb` model.